# Search a string after match

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep

I have a file which has multiple record of netstat output, my sample file looks something like the one below. I want to search for PID for ex : 3453, part of the output I also want to see snapshot time, so that I can find whether PID was exist part of particular snapshot or not. Any thoughts?

```
zzz ***Sat Apr 11 03:00:26 UTC 2020
USER        PID   PPID PRI %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS WCHAN             S  STARTED     TIME COMMAND
test    1234  3445  19  2.4  1.9 4070932 3539756 futex_wait_queue_ S   Apr 04 04:00:17 test -quiet
test1    3453  6741  19  2.4  1.9 4070932 3539756 futex_wait_queue_ S   Apr 04 04:00:17 test -quiet

zzz ***Sat Apr 11 03:01:26 UTC 2020
USER        PID   PPID PRI %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS WCHAN             S  STARTED     TIME COMMAND
test    3453  3453  19  2.4  1.9 4070932 3539756 futex_wait_queue_ S   Apr 04 04:00:17 test -quiet
test1    7842  8712  19  2.4  1.9 4070932 3539756 futex_wait_queue_ S   Apr 04 04:00:17 test -quiet
```

## Expected sample output for search 3453:

```
zzz ***Sat Apr 11 03:00:26 UTC 2020
test1    3453  6741  19  2.4  1.9 4070932 3539756 futex_wait_queue_ S   Apr 04 04:00:17 test -quiet
zz ***Sat Apr 11 03:01:26 UTC 2020
test    3453  3453  19  2.4  1.9 4070932 3539756 futex_wait_queue_ S   Apr 04 04:00:17 test -quiet
```

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting, but I'm not sure I did it correctly. Please, make sure the sample data are correct (e.g. the three asterisks or the newline between the blocks). Also, please include what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question and let us know then.

Comment: "egrep '(string1|string2)' filename.dat " its all what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/\*\*\*/,/^$/{ /\*\*\*/p; /3453/p }' file
```

Output:

```
zzz ***Sat Apr 11 03:00:26 UTC 2020
test1    3453  6741  19  2.4  1.9 4070932 3539756 futex_wait_queue_ S   Apr 04 04:00:17 test -quiet
zzz ***Sat Apr 11 03:01:26 UTC 2020
test    3453  3453  19  2.4  1.9 4070932 3539756 futex_wait_queue_ S   Apr 04 04:00:17 test -quiet
```

---

See: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)